# cable housing with braided metal hard to cut?

Tags: cable, cable-housing

Jagwire makes some cable housings that look like braided metal (called "sterling silver", "titanium", "carbon silver", and "gold"). I have a vague recollection of a review that said these metallic housings are more difficult to cut than the solid colored ones. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

(I have a decent bicycle cable/housing cutter that worked fine on the solid colored Jagwire housings.)

Comment: With the right tools anything is possible.  I'd suspect the reviewer used diagonal pliars or sidecutters instead of the proper recurved blade pliars.   (TBH I don't own the right tool either, I use a hacksaw, vice, file and sharpened spoke for cutting housings to length.)

Comment: For those without the right tool, a Dremel with a cutting wheel works very well.

Answer (score 5):

I can't confirm, but it's worth noting that if the reviewer was a do-it-yourselfer, then they might've been trying to cut it with a pair of regular wire cutters instead of a bicycle-appropriate pair of cable cutters. As long as your cable cutters are sharp, you should be able to snip it without excessive trouble.

Comment: Thanks. That may well have been the case. Like I said, it's just a vague memory and I don't remember the details, hence my asking here.

Comment: I have used my Park Tool cable cutters on this housing with no issues.  I actually think it cuts a bit cleaner.  As with any housing its best to clip it hard and fast.